Digital Ocean Kubernetes droplet nginx-ingress not getting IP of LoadBalancer
I've setup a load balancer to direct traffic to two droplets running kube workers.
However the loadbalancer still show 0 and nginx-ingress still at 
All services and pods are running and functioning will.
I followed the setup here
Nginx Ingress on Digital Ocean using Helm
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.publishService.enabled=true

After, I run
kubectl --namespace default get services -o wide -w nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
Which gives the output
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.110.194.184   <pending>     80:31544/TCP,443:30700/TCP   46m

Per the documentation should show up, Nonetheless went ahead and create the LoadBalancer and forwarded to the pod ports and added the added the worker nodes droplets to the  LoadBalancer
Droplet shows 0 and nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller Cluster IP still at Pending.
